# UI to edit a list item within the current template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My UI includes nested tabs (using Bootstrap). The tab in question is a template with its own controller, currently specified on a view with UI-Router:

```
.state('editBase.edit', {
    url: '/:id',
    views: {
        'fooTab@editBase.edit': {
            templateUrl: 'foo.html',
            controller: 'FooController'
        },
        // more views...
```

The template uses `ng-repeat` to create a list of links. Each link goes to an editor child state:

```
<a ui-sref="editBase.edit.subEdit({itemId: item.id})">{{item.name}}</a>
```

What I want to happen when the link is clicked is for the contents of the tab (the list) to be replaced with the editor. On clicking a save button, the list would reappear refreshed.

I'm not looking for an in-place editor for a list; I want to hide the entire list, but leave the surrounding templates/tabs intact. In other words, I don't want to replace the root view. How can I do this?

**Note:** I found [this post](http://www.funnyant.com/angularjs-ui-router/) that explains multiple nested views and view names; this helped me a lot.

Comment: Can you just set `contenteditable=true` on the said list item, and attach that to a click event? (This is assuming you have a solution that turns that list item into an in-place editable element.)

Comment: @frishi Currently I'm not looking for in-place edit capabilities.

Comment: Does it need to be another child route? Quite simple to do it using `ng-if` within same controller and view. `ng-if` also supports animations for transitioning

Comment: @charlietfl That's an idea I might have to explore. My hope was that UI-Router would handle the state transitions, parameters, separation of templates/controllers, etc.

Comment: Can certainly do it with child route...not sure if you need that url to be accessible or not. As far as templates go those are simple to manage in `<my-editor>` directive also. Overall not really clear what your current stumbling block is

Comment: @charlietfl I don't need deep linking here, so the URL should not change. I'm looking for a simple example of doing this with UI-Router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edit state, create a view that targets the list's `<ui-view>`

#### A parent state, just for demonstration.  The parent state has a ui-view that the list state plugs into

```
$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'app',
  template: '<div ui-view="list"></div>'
});
```

#### The list state targets the <ui-view="list">, which was created by the parent state

```
$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'app.list',
  url: '/objects',
  views: {
    list: {
      controller: ...
      template: `<ul><li ng-repeat="..."></li></ul>
    }
  }
});
```

#### The edit state targets the <ui-view="list"> that was created by the `app` state.  The `ui-view` was previously filled in by the app.list state.  However, the child state's view targeting that `ui-view` takes precedence over the parent state view.

```
$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'app.list.edit',
  url: '/edit/:id',
  views: {
    "list@app": {
      controller: ...
      template: "<a ui-sref="^">Go back...</a><form>...</form>"
    }
  }
}) ;
```

Here's a working plunker that demonstrates it: http://plnkr.co/edit/Uc39R2ZHUg2Ru3xyEkfe?p=preview